# How to open an .tn3 file on Windows 10 HP laptop computer?

Tags: windows

Need to know how to open file extension `.tn3` on Windows 10 laptop or which program to use or download?

Answer (score 1):

A TN3 file is from Atari computers

[TN3 file](https://fileinfo.com/extension/tn3#:%7E:text=A%20TN3%20file%20is%20a,or%20may%20not%20be%20animated.&text=The%20TN3%20format%20is%20one,used%20by%20Atari%20ST%20computers.)

> A TN3 file is a bitmap image used by Atari ST computers, which Atari
> released in the late 1980s and early 1990s. It contains an
> RLE-compressed image that may or may not be animated. If the image is
> animated, the TNE3 file contains multiple bitmap frames and the
> animation sequence's speed and duration
>
> The TN3 format is one of several Tiny image formats used by Atari ST
> computers. Tiny images are also stored in low-resolution (.TN1 files)
> and medium-resolution (.TN2 files) formats. They may also be saved
> with the .TNY extension.

If you need to open a TN3 file, a HEX editor would be your best bet. Lots of HEX editors around. I use Ultra Edit.